# Django Production Issue Serving Media Root Files

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

I checked for the same issue and found some tips none of them however worked.
In Debug mode everything works like a charm. You can access the file with the www address and a user can upload a picture.
Now i turned the debug off, at first i was using the debug settings just with the debug turned off. The Upload still worked but the picture couldn't be loaded via www (404 Error). Then i changed it to the settings live, now the upload doesn't work and the media_root files are not served via www.

I checked on my server and changed the access to write read, didn't help.

Any idea on how to fix this?

settings.py debug:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
) 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "media_root")
```

settings.py live:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT =  '/var/www/vhosts/bspotted1/app/static_in_pro/static_root/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     '/var/www/vhosts/bspotted1/app/static_in_pro/',
    #'/var/www/static/',
) 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/vhosts/bspotted1/app/static_in_pro/media_root/'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: In production you are supposed to serve the STATIC_ROOT directory from a  webserver like nginx or apache, why are you triyng to serve them from Django? Is there any constraint on your platform?

Comment: In addition to Paulo Scardines answer, check whether you have configured ` + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in your urls.py

Comment: @PauloScardine It is an apache server or am i miss understanding something, and they are served via directory? Updated my post with my urls.py. I don't think there are any constraints.

Comment: Please take a look at [Serving files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) section from the Django documents.

Comment: @PauloScardine The Hosting Service Changed the Conf file, now if i turn the debug off nothing works. Not even the Static Files.

Comment: You are asking  random strangers on the Internet donate their time instead of contacting the support channel from your hosting service that is paid to solve your hosting problems. You are asking about a problem that we are unable to reproduce, even if we are willing to help you. Sorry, I wish you good luck but I will vote to close your question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your webserver to serve static and media files.

Django is not meant to serve them. Instead Django will just refer to the STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL prefixes to lookup/upload files.

In debug mode a web daemon is run to server the files temporarily which is not supposed to be used in production.